# DESeq2 code help for analysing differential gene expression between disease and control patients in R

Tags: r, bioinformatics, bioconductor, rna-seq

I am having trouble devising some correct code to work out using DESeq2 in R, how to look at which genes are more highly expressed in the disease patients compared to the control.

My data is currently a large data frame consisting of 600000 gene names which are rows. The first three columns [1:3] are control patients and the last three are from pancreatic cancer patients [4:6].

```
DF = data.frame(id=colnames(genetable),type=rep(c("treat","ctrl"),each=3))
# run DESeq2
dds = DESeqDataSetFromMatrix(genetable,DF,~type)
ddsoutput <- DESeq(dds)
summary(results(dds),alpha=0.05)
```

To get the number of genes which are below 0.05;

```
res <- results(ddsoutput)
res[which(res$padj < 0.05),]
```

I then need to work out fold change between disease vs control, both upregulated and downregulated. I need to set my own fold change threshold, and then analyse the function of the most upregulated or downregulated genes based on my p values via KEGG;

```
 upreg <- subset(res, log2FoldChange > 1)

 downreg <- subset(res, log2FoldChange < 1)
```

But none of the above is working, I think I am going wrong by using type=rep maybe? I ultimately need to save the p value and log fold change value into a table.

Comment: deseq2 is well documented here: https://www.bioconductor.org/packages/devel/bioc/vignettes/DESeq2/inst/doc/DESeq2.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there's a bug in your code, I corrected it below, and placed the previous it under ##. You replace the original DESeq2 object with the output of the function DESeq()

```
DF = data.frame(id=colnames(genetable),type=rep(c("treat","ctrl"),each=3))
# run DESeq2
dds = DESeqDataSetFromMatrix(genetable,DF,~type)
dds <- DESeq(dds)
# it was
# ddsoutput <- DESeq(dds)
summary(results(dds),alpha=0.05)
```

Now run the rest of the script and it should be fine

Comment: please could you tell me whether I would need to add normalisation=T in the code. Would this need to go after alpha=0.05? I am doing some downstream analysis where I think the data needs to be normalised. Thank-you

Comment: Hi @Saramy, the normalization is done inside the wrapper DESeq. It runs estimateSizeFactors() to get normalization factors which it uses downstream. The only point to use normalization=TRUE is to get counts, e.g counts(dds,normalize=TRUE) if this is what you are referring to

Comment: I am not sure how, but when I run this I can see that some pvalues and padjust for quite a lot of genes are NA, whilst a log2FoldChange has been calculated. Please could you tell me why this might be?

Comment: Hi @Saramy, you can check https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/vignettes/DESeq2/inst/doc/DESeq2.html#why-are-some-p-values-set-to-na

Comment: If any answer solved your question you can consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this (definitely no obligation in this case).

Comment: And @Saramy I solved your previous problem.. If there is a new issue, please open another question and close this.

Comment: Thank-you, I will turn cooks cut off to false and see what happens.

Comment: Thanks @Saramy. If your problem is having too many NAs for p-values, it could be that you have too many zeros. do you have single cell data? If so, you need to use seurat.

Comment: One final question, this may be silly but in the order of type=rep(c("ctrl", "treat"), each=3, where cols 1:3 are control and cols 4:6 are disease. Where the log2FoldChanges are > 1, it shows the genes upregulated in control relative to disease. I need the output to show up and down regulated genes in disease relative to control. Is there any way I can change the formula so it shows this? Thank you

Comment: you do type=factor(rep(c("ctrl", "treat"), each=3),levels=c("ctrl","treat")) or with your current DESeq2 obj, do results(dds,contrast=c("type","treat","ctrl"))

Comment: To add to @StupidWolf 's excellent answers in the comments, If you want are more explicitly explanation on the noramlization in DESeq2, I can recommend Statquests videos on this - heres part 1: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UFB993xufUU

Comment: @halfer, I think makes more sense to roll it back to the original version. OP added more modifications to make it a new question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58983834/overcoming-na-values-in-deseq2-outlier-and-filtering-adjustments