# Overcoming NA values in DESEq2 (outlier and filtering adjustments)

Tags: r

My import data is a large gene count table containing 598,019 bacterial genes in the rows, and three control samples compared to three disease samples ( as columns). Here are a few lines of my data. Cols 1:3 are control, Cols 4:6 are disease. It follows a zero inflated negative binomial distribution.

NODE1length36040cov12.43651 37 0 2 0 0 0 NODE1length36040cov12.43653 1 0 0 0 0 0 
NODE2length32139cov10.31191 187 0 3 0 0 0 NODE2length32139cov10.31192 97 0 6 0 0 0 
NODE2length32139cov10.31193 162 0 0 0 0 0 NODE3length27992cov10.59761 16 0 0 0 0 0

```
               gctab <- read.csv("final.gene.count.table1.nonzero.csv", row.names=1)
               DF = data.frame(id=colnames(gctab),type=rep(c("ctrl","disease"),each=3))

               dds = DESeqDataSetFromMatrix(gctab,DF,~type)
               dds <- DESeq(dds)


      res <- results(dds, alpha=0.05, contrast=c("type", "disease", "ctrl"))
      summary(res)
```

I did plot boxplots for Cooks distances for each of the samples, and they were all pretty similar.

1) With Cooks cut off, these are my results; 
out of 598019 with nonzero total read count adjusted p-value < 0.05; LFC > 0 (up) : 965, 0.16%; LFC < 0 (down) : 111, 0.019%; outliers [1] : 12602, 2.1% ; low counts [2] : 0, 0%

A lot of the p values and padj are NA as expected.

2)Turning Cooks cut off to False gets these results;
out of 598019 with nonzero total read count; adjusted p-value < 0.05; LFC > 0 (up) : 3885, 0.65% ; LFC < 0 (down) : 1918, 0.32% ; outliers [1] : 0, 0% ; low counts [2] : 568118, 95% (mean count < 11)

A lot of padj values are now NA

I would prefer not to turn independent filtering off, would the only alternative be to change alpha ( which I wasn't too keen on doing either)? Please could you help if you have any suggestions with regards to ways I can overcome a lot of NAs in my padj output?

Thank-you,

Answer (score 0):

An important aspect to consider with DeSeq is to consider if indeed you want to force estimation of p values for genes where cools cutoff fails. DEseq given the distribution is saying there is not enough data to make an estimate of the pvalues. This is not too unexpected given the low Ns